# How to monitor heavy/long task MongoDB queries?

Tags: mongodb

After restart my node app the MongoDB process (mongod) bursts the cpu to 300-400% for 10 seconds - causing downtime.

I want to know WHY. That could be more than awesome if I could just get a mail/log report of queries (read and also write) filtered by queries that took more than X seconds, or X% cpu / RAM.

Comment: This is just a list of monitoring strategies and tools: [Monitoring for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/).

Comment: Check db.system.profile for slow queries, check mongod logs what happens after restart, e.g. number of connections.  Check db.currentOp() when you restart nodejs app.